# Which Service for Messaging and E-commerce Should I Use?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native, backend

I am starting a project in react native that will be an mobile app with some functionalities:

Check for products and select it for buying; A chat between the company and the user;Push Notifications; Login; Payment System; Monthly reports.

I would like to know if anyone suggests something specific for the back end.
I have only knowledge in MySQL, and I am looking for the best technology for this project.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Choosing the best backend solution depends on many variables. The best question always is how much money you have and how flexible solution you want. Also it is not only programming language you have to choose. Also platform, database type (SQL, NoSQL), database software (MongoDB, DynamoDB, PostgreSQL, etc.)

I recommend Go as a programming language and MongoDB for such project, all can be running as a docker containers on AWS with solutions like ALB and API Gateway. Maybe lambda.

You can also consider using Firebase as the cheaper alternative. It is quite powerful. Instead of AWS you can choose Heroku.